# Script not Found: 404

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js

The name of my project is "Basketball."  I have a "views" folder.  One of the files in "views" is "profile," which is a page for user to change profile.

I added a folder to Basketball, which I named, "scripts."  Inside scripts, I added a file, "profile.js."

In my view, I have at the end:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/profile.js"></script>
```

When I run the app, I get an error:

```
 GET http://localhost:3000/scripts/profile.js 404 (Not Found)
```

Aside from failing to load the script, the view works fine.

What is wrong with my path?  Or is there some other mistake?

Comment: try `src="scripts/profile.js"`. Remove `/` before `scripts` in src

Comment: @UsmanRana, it results in GET http://localhost:3000/users/scripts/profile.js 404 (Not Found).

Comment: is `profile.js` there in the path `users/scripts/profile.js` ?

Comment: There's no way to know without knowing what kind of server you have, what the document root (or equivalent) it's set to, what the routing is...

Comment: can you please tell the relative path of `profiles.js` with your file where you're including this script ?

Comment: The project name is "Basketball."  That's my root, which I assume is the same as localhost:3000.  The scripts folder is directly beneath Basketball.  I am running a nodejs app.

Comment: View is:  Basketball/views/profile.handlebars.  Script is: Basketball/scripts/profile.js.

Comment: how are you serving the requested file ? can you please post your that part of the code too ?

Comment: @Usan Rana, Ah!  I do not have an getter in my router file for this script.  Are you saying I need to add a get handler for any of my own scripts I include?

Comment: yes ofcourse you need to do that. well I am posting it as answer. You can check the detailed answer in there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159337/discussion-between-usman-rana-and-jeff-matthews).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When even you include some `script/css/image` or anyother file you need to set its router on server side to serve that file to browser (unless you use some other module to do that for you like [express](https://expressjs.com/)). If you don't want to use `express`, what I would recommend you to do, you can write a `router` on your server side. Something like

```
if(req.url === '/scripts/profile.js' ){
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-type' : 'text/javascript'});
fs.createReadStream(path.join(path.join(__dirname,'scripts/profile.js'),'split.css'), 'utf8' ).pipe(res)
```

}